# Generate a PDF from printdocument

Tags: c#, pdf, savefiledialog, printdocument, print-preview

i want to save my printpage into pdf document, i'm using  printpreviewdialog and print document

```
    private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         printPreviewDialog.Document = printDocument;
         printPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
    private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lbGam.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbGam.Items[i].ToString(), new Font("Lucida Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(50, y));
            y = y + 25;
        }
        y = 450;
        for (int i = 0; i < lbProduct.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbProduct.Items[i].ToString(), new Font("Lucida Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(220, y));
            y = y + 25;
        }
        y = 450;
        for (int i = 0; i < lbPrice.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbPrice.Items[i].ToString(), new Font("Lucida Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(720, y));
            y = y + 25;
        }
        try
        {
            newImage = pbVehicle.Image;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 520, 250);
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        { }  
    }
```

I can print it, but now I want to save it to a file, or in printpreviewdialog a save as button

Comment: Where are you stuck? What is your issue?

Comment: i just print the page, i want to save this like a pdf document

Comment: have you tried to use PDFSharp or iTextSharp libraries? By using this you can create pdf document.